# Chebyshev's Inequality Proof Step

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a (maybe straightforward) step in the proof of Chebyshev's inequality:

$$
P(|X-\bar X| \geq a) \leq \frac{\sigma^{2}}{a^{2}} \quad (1)
$$

The proof starts with the Markov's inequality
$$
P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E[X]}{a} \quad (2)
$$

And it is used to prove Chebyshev's inequality by replacing $X$ by $Y = (X - \bar X)^2$, which results in

$$
P((X-\bar X)^2 \geq a^2) \leq \frac{E[(X-\bar X)^2]}{a^{2}} \quad (3)
$$

Then it gives (1)

Why is it $a^2$ in the right-hand side $\frac{E[(X-\bar X)^2]}{a^{2}}$ and just not $a$?

Answer (score 1):

That is a good question. It is a small point that has to do with a change of variables. Markov's Inequality says that **for any** $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0},\; P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a}$.
Therefore, we can let $b = a^2$. For clarity, let's prove Chebyschev's Inequality outright from Markov's
$$
\begin{align}
P(X \geq b) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{b}\\
\textit{Let } Y = (X-\overline{X})^2 \\
\Rightarrow P((X-\overline{X})^2 \geq b) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X-\overline{X})^2]}{b} \\
\boxed{\text{Let } b = a^2} \\
\Rightarrow P((X-\overline{X})^2 \geq a^2) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X-\overline{X})^2]}{a^2} \\
\text{Using } (X-\overline{X})^2 \geq a^2 \Leftrightarrow 
|(X-\overline{X})| \geq a \\ 
\qquad \text{and } \mathbb{E}[(X-\overline{X})^2] = Var(X) = \sigma^2 \\
\Rightarrow P(|(X-\overline{X})| \geq a) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}
\end{align}
$$
Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You actually use the variable

$$ |X-E(X)|$$

So putting square root in the probability doesn't affected the right term.

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited it. My question was about why it is $a^2$ in the Right-hand side and just not $a$?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing variables name can be helpful.
Markov inequality states for every nonnegative random variable $Z$ and every positive $b$ that:
\begin{equation*}
P(Z \geq b) \leq \frac{E[Z]}{b}.
\end{equation*}
You need to apply this inequality with $Z=(X-\bar{X})^2$ and $b=a^2$. Keep in mind that:
\begin{equation*}
(X-\bar{X})^2 \geq a^2 \Leftrightarrow \lvert X-\bar{X} \rvert \geq a
\end{equation*}
since $a$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't notice it was $b$ that was also replaced